# What's the difference between ' and #' in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, quote

It seems both

```
(mapcar 'car '((foo bar) (foo1 bar1)))
```

and

```
(mapcar #'car '((foo bar) (foo1 bar1)))
```

work as the same.

And I also know `'` means (quote symbol) and `#'` means (function function-name).

But what's the underlying difference? Why these 2 both work in previous `mapcar`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
'foo
```

evaluates to the symbol FOO.

```
#'foo
```

evaluates to the function bound to the name FOO.

In Lisp a symbol can be called as a function when the symbol FOO has a function binding. Here CAR is a symbol that has a function binding.

But this does not work:

```
(flet ((foo (a) (+ a 42)))
  (mapcar 'foo '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

That's because FOO as a symbol does not access the local lexical function and the Lisp system will complain when `foo` is not a function defined elsewhere.

We need to write:

```
(flet ((foo (a) (+ a 42)))
  (mapcar #'foo '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

Here the (function foo) or its shorthand notation #'foo refers to the lexical local function FOO.

Note also that in

```
(funcall #'foo ...)
```

vs.

```
(funcall 'foo ...)
```

The later might do one more indirection, since it needs to lookup the function from the symbol, while #'foo denotes the function directly.

**Summary**:

If a symbol has a function binding, calling a function through the symbol works.

Answer (score 10):

> Why these 2 both work in previous mapcar?

The documentation for [mapcar](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) says:

> If function is a symbol, it is coerced to a function as if by [symbol-function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_1.htm#symbol-function).

Answer (score 3):

Try passing an anonymous function (lambda) to your `mapcar` and you'll see that `#'` is required since the quote by itself expects a symbol that is bound to a function, but the symbol doesn't exist in an un-named function:

```
CL-USER> (mapcar '(lambda (x) (format t "it is ~d" x)) (list 3 5 7))
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: (OR FUNCTION SYMBOL)
             datum: (LAMBDA (X) (FORMAT T "it is ~d" X))>.
```

vs:

```
CL-USER> (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (format t "it is ~d" x)) (list 3 5 7))
it is 3it is 5it is 7
(NIL NIL NIL)
```